# Get ID's of multiple inserted rows (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, orm

is it possible to receive the id of multiple inserted rows?
I know that after saving (`$post->save()`) the post object will receive an id after save. But what if I have inserted array of posts? will I get their id's too?

I am asking this because I am trying to create a many new posts which has many comments (each post may have zero or many comments). Both the posts and the comments are not yet created in the DB.

For this I want first to save the posts and then save the comments. Not sure if it is the best way though...

Thanks!

Comment: I meant which "database" are you using!

Comment: mysql.......................

Answer (score 0):

If you use loop for inserting post, Probably in each iteration you can get new id!!!

Comment: the problem is: multiple queries. I would like to avoid this

Comment: if your application is single user(i meant one user connect to DB each time) you could use top statement to get multiple insert IDs